# How to get two rows value

Tags: sql, mysql, string

Using mysql

I want to display two rows values in to single value

```
ID  Name
---------
01  Raja
02  Ravi
```

Expected output:

```
01Raja
02Ravi
```

How to make a query for this condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select Concat(ID, Name)
from MyTable
```

Answer (score 4):

You can call [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONVERT(ID, VARCHAR(8)), Name)
FROM SomeWhere
```

Comment: Small correction, Mysql (at least version 5) doesn't CONVERT to type VARCHAR(). You have to use `CONCAT(CONVERT(ID, CHAR(8)), Name)` for this to work but I think you're better using no convert at all (Red Filter suggestion)